# How to pass multiline textbox text to crystal report in windows form application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have Form in c# with multiline textbox.
I want to send multiline textbox text to crystal report formula field.
I know how to pass textbox text.

Kindly provide code snippet or article that would demonstrate the same.

For Ex:I/P in Multi line textbox is :

```
Hello
World
```

O/P in crystal report should be:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: I know it's late but this came up in a search result of mine. have you solved the issue? Is the text appearing in one line or just showing the first?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used this

```
string test = "";
string multilinetextboxvalue = multiline.text;
string[] parseLines = multilinetextboxvalue.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string line in parseLines)
{ test += line + "' & chr(010) & '"; }
test = test.remove(test.Length -16, 16);
multiline.text = "'" + test + "'";
```